# Method in Paypal API to retrieve transaction status

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to use paypal API in my project, I was wondering if there is any method in which I can pass paypal url, username, password and subscription id(which is of my transaction)and retrieve status like subscription started, cancelled, status.

Comment: What are you using? What have you tried?